# Joda time - Parsing string throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, jodatime, date-formatting, date-parsing

Shouldn't a `String` formatted with a specific `DateTimeFormatter` be able to be parsed using `LocalDateTime.parse()`?

**Test**

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis()
LocalDateTime ldt = new LocalDateTime()
String val = ldt.toString(formatter)
System.out.println(val) //2013-03-26T13:10:46
// parse() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2013-03-26T13:10:46" is too short
LocalDateTime nldt = LocalDateTime.parse(val, formatter)
```

Comment: I would say this is a bug with JodaTime. It should parse any string with format as well as formatter is object of DateTimeFormatter which is not happening.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the [JavaDoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#basicDateTimeNoMillis%28%29):

> Returns a basic formatter that combines a basic date and time without millis, separated by a 'T' (yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ). The time zone offset is 'Z' for zero, and of the form '±HHmm' for non-zero. The parser is strict by default, thus time string 24:00 cannot be parsed.

The key here seems to be *The time zone offset is 'Z' for zero, and of the form '±HHmm' for non-zero*. Joda Time obviously expects time zone information for `parse()`.

I appended `"Z"` to your parsed date String and it works better:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
LocalDateTime ldt = new LocalDateTime();
String val = ldt.toString(formatter);
System.out.println(val);    
val += "Z";
LocalDateTime nldt = LocalDateTime.parse(val, formatter);
System.out.println(nldt.toString());
```

Output is:

```
2013-03-26T17:50:06
2013-03-26T17:50:06.000
```

Answer (score 2):

The formatter also throws the error if `formatter.parseLocalDateTime(val)` is called, which is what `LocalDateTime.parse(...)` is calling directly (ie, the naive call).

So, then, it's a factor of the format that is expected - which in this case is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ`; basically, it's complaining that you haven't passed a timezone.

I don't know if this actually qualifies as a 'bug'; in the short term, obviously a custom format may be used, or look at [ISODateTimeFormat.localDateOptionalTimeParser()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#localDateOptionalTimeParser%28%29), which appears to be what you want (it's the default parser used by `LocalDateTime`).